# Button images don't show when wpf app is running

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a play and resume button in my wpf application. When I'm designing I see the buttons on my window but when I run the application, the images are gone. Why?

[image]

Comment: Pictures of code are annoying, Just saying

Comment: @Saruman I know but it's easier to show this then just typing a lot of text cause the problem is not with any code

Comment: Have you set the *Build Action* of the image to `Resource`?

Comment: @Abbas well that was easy, thank you

Comment: @Machtelinckx_ I provided my comment as an answer so this question can be 'closed' by marking an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I provided the answer as a comment, but here it is in answer format:

Try setting the *Build Action* of the image to `Resource`.